# how to disable free hand drawing on google map when clear button is pressed

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I am working on project which needs to add free hand drawing on google map.I have done drawing successfully on google map. But my problem is when i clicked clear button it remove all things what ever i draw on map but i does not disable the edit mode that means when i touched screen again then it again started drawing.

i want when i clicked clear button, it clear every thing and again map is in initial mode as it is before.

here are some screenshot

1.[this screenshot after clicking clear button and still i am able to draw on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEUv0.png)

here are some relative code...

this is under my map activity

```
private void drawOnMap() {
        mcontent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(signature);
        save_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        save_button.setEnabled(false);
        exit_edit_mode = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exit_edit_mode);
        mSignature = new signature(this, null);
        mcontent.addView(mSignature);

        save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mSignature.save();
            }
        });
        exit_edit_mode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mSignature.clear();
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

this is my class which perform drawing on google map

```
public class signature extends View {
    static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 10f;
    static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path path = new Path();

    float lastTouchX;
    float lastTouchY;
    final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
        save_button.setEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        //save.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I got my solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it by my self
add this code after

```
msignature.clear()
mcontent.removeView(mSignature);
```